# Finding global minumum maximum

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

How can I find the global min/max in this problem?
Find the critical points of the function :
f(x,y)=$2x^3-3x^2y-12x^2-3y^2$
and determine their type.
**Are there any global min/max?**

The critical points were:  (0,0),
(2,-2),(-4,-8)
  By using the hessian matrix I found their types:
(0,0) is a local maximum
(-4,-8) is a saddle
(2,-2) is a saddle.

But I do not understand how to find the global minimum or maximum.
I know that if the Hessian matrix is negative semi definite then any local max is a global max and if Hessian matrix is a positive semi definite then any local min is  a global min.

Please help me to find the global minimum /maximum?

Comment: also investigate unbounded conditions - [like here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/402105/1121385) - to do the conclusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look on x-axis, as x is increasing f(x,y) is also increasing
similarly on y-axis as y is increasing ; f(x,y) is decreasing, so there is no global max, min.

Comment: checking what happens to the function as x increases and y increases is that a method to find global min /max

Comment: absolutely it's not the method but by way of contradiction if max occurs at a point then there should be no point where greater than max value occur. but here always we can have such a point.

Comment: So I have to check the behavior of the function (y->infinity,x=0) and (x->infinity,y=0)

Comment: it depends on problem Mr.clarkson

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a global maximum or minimum, at least not when considered on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Set $y=0$ and you can easily see that your function neither has an upper nor lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the highest power of $x$ is 3. So if you make $x$ large positive then $f$ is also large positive (just set $y=0$). Similarly if you make $x$ large negative, $f$ will be large negative.

So *no* global maximima/minima